# Thread 1 is executing in java synchronized method 1, can Thread 2 then execute in java synchronised method 2?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Was wondering if someone could help clear this up for me. (Student)

Say we have two threads, "Thread1" & "Thread2". If Thread1 is executing in method 1 can Thread2 then execute in method2?

```
void method1() {
    synchronized (this) {
    }
}

void method2() {
    synchronized (this) {
    }
}
```

I'm either thinking yes, Thread2 can enter as "this" is just the instance of that method or no because "this" is the instance of that class and Thread1 holds onto it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a monitor associated with a specific *method* - there's a monitor associated with an *object*. So if you're trying to synchronize on the same object in both methods, the second thread will block until the first thread releases the monitor.

(Personally I don't like synchronizing on `this` anyway - I synchronize on a reference to an object that *only* my class has access to. But that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 4):

Everybody jumped on an obvious answer here.  It is a correct answer, but it is not the *only* correct answer.

The rule is, two threads can not both synchronize on the same object at the same time.  But does `this` refer to the same object in both method calls?  We can't tell because you have not shown us the calls.  Consider this example:

```
class Demo {

    synchronized void method1() {
        ...do something...
    }

    synchronized void method2() {
        ...do something else...
    }

    static void caseA() {
        final Demo demo = new Demo();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                demo.method1();
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                demo.method2();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static void caseB() {
        final Demo demo1 = new Demo();
        final Demo demo2 = new Demo();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                demo1.method1();
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                demo2.method2();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

In caseA(), the calls to demo.method1() and demo.method2() can not overlap because both calls synchronize on the same object, but in caseB() the two calls are synchronized on two *different instances* of the Demo class.  In caseB() the method1() call and the method2() call *can* overlap.

Comment: So the "this" depends on where/how it is being called, that makes sense, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: I suppose this is why people advocate using an object only accessible by that class rather than "this"?

Comment: @KevinPaton the main reason for using a private Object just for locking is, it prevents anybody else from synchronizing on it.  _Any_ object can be used for locking.  It would be a really bone-head move, but some developer could use an instance of your class to synchronize something _else_.  If you use a private object that he can't see for your synchronization, then your synchronization and his can not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `this` for synchronization, which is an instance of an object. Synchronization always works on some particular instance of object and only one thread at any given time can acquire lock of (synchronize on) a single instance used for synchronization and.

Both threads can access the methods only if they use separate instances of the object containing those methods.

Answer (score 1):

The second thread will block until the monitor is released by the first as synchronization is done on the same object for both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better synchronized on the static object you want to lock.
Here, your method 2 will be executed by thread 2, but the content of the `synchronized` block in method 2 will not be executed unless thread 1 has unlock `this`. Since your synchronization is on a block, and not on a method, the method is not synchronized, but the block is.

If you have a static member on which you want work in the synchronized, use it like:

```
private static List<Object> myList;



 void method1() {
    synchronized (myList) {
        // do something on myList
    }
}

void method2() {
    synchronized (myList) {
       // do something  on myList
    }
}
```

Comment: "You'd better synchronized on the static object you want to lock."  There's a couple of problems with that:  (1) The object you want to lock might not be static.  (2) The _thing_ that you want to lock might not be a single object.  It might be an important relationship that must be maintained between _several_ objects.  (3) You might prefer to synchronize on a hidden, private Object even though the object(s) that you wish to protect are exposed to callers.

Comment: Yes, you're true. I was thinking the synchronized was for a static purpose in this case, but maybe this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

No Thread2 will have to wait until Thread1 is finished executing the code in synchronised block. This is because you are using the same object (this) to lock. If you did something like this:

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = new Object();

void method1() {
    synchronized (lock1) { }
}


void method2() {
    synchronized (lock2) { }
}
```

Then you would be able to have Thread1 execute method1 and Thread2 execute method2.

Comment: "...You are using the same object (this) to lock."   The original example does not show that.  It only shows two method _declarations_.  We can't know without seeing the method _invocations_ whether or not `this` refers to the same object in both calls, or whether it refers to a different instance of the same class in each call.